# In Python how do I assign two different counts of something to a same variable?

Tags: python

I have the number of A's to count but in one of cell of an excel its 'A' & in some cells its 'A '

So, If the cell has 'A' I want my code to count no of 'A' and store in count_a, else if my cell has 'A ' I also want that to be counted and stored in same variable count_a.

```
def config(status: []) -> None:
    global count_a
    count_a = status.count('A' or 'A ')
```

This code somehow seems to be not working, Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Just add the results of "status.count" for "A" and "A ".

Comment: Status.count(‘A’)+status.count(‘A ‘)

Comment: Normalise your data using `strip()` and use `collections.Counter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because `status.count('A' or 'A ')` does not even close what you think it does. It does not count "`A`"s and "`A` "s. It counts "`True`"s, because first the expression `'A' or 'A '` is evaluated, which results in `True` and then `count()` counts.

You have to count them separately:

```
count_a = status.count('A')
count_a += status.count('A ')
```

or

```
count_a = status.count('A') + status.count('A ')
```